# Error: ER_INVALID_JSON_TEXT: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value for column '._data'. IN NODE JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to insert JOSN data/object into mysql using stored procedure using node js. First of all I know there are some similar question out there but I tried them and but still didn't get the result.

This is the first time I am using stored procedure and node js, So I have table name `test_data`

**test_data**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

This is stored procedure `insert_data`:

```
insert_data

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_data`(
    IN `_data` JSON

)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    declare p_name varchar(255) default null;
    declare p_address varchar(255) default null;
    declare p_city varchar(255) default null;

    set p_name= json_unquote(json_extract(_data, '$.name'));
    set p_address= json_unquote(json_extract(_data, '$.address'));
    set p_city= json_unquote(json_extract(_data, '$.city'));        

    insert into test_data(name, address, city) values(p_name, p_address, p_city);
END
```

here is my `node js` code :

```
const con = require('./db/connection');

const _data = {
    "name": "Ironman",
    "address": "ani@gamil.com",
    "city": "bhilai"
}
const sql = "CALL insert_data('"+_data +"')"
con.query(sql, _data,(error, result) => {

    if(error){
        return console.log("There is error in the query: " + error)
    }
    console.log(result)
})
```

**ERROR**

```
There is error in the query: Error: ER_INVALID_JSON_TEXT: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value for column '._data'.
```

please help me out here, what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not actually passing a JSON value?

```
const _data = {
    "name": "Ironman",
    "address": "ani@gamil.com",
    "city": "bhilai"
};
```

The above is a Javascript **object**, not its JSON representation. So here

```
const sql = "CALL insert_data('"+_data +"')"
```

the actual value of `sql` will be `"CALL insert_data('[object Object]')"` which is in fact not valid. Try dumping `sql` to console to verify that this is indeed the case.

Try with:

```
const sql = "CALL insert_data('"+ JSON.stringify(_data) +"')"
```